# Curl Command Send Asynchronous Request

Tags: bash, scripting, curl

I using this curl request for sending data to API :

```
curl --location --request POST 'MY_IP' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw ' [{
    "event_id": "123",
}]    
'
```

I want to check the API performance by sending request asynchronously and measure the time take I tried to use `xargs -P 10` which say send 10 request parallel but not able to do so ? Any help and how I can measure time ?

My Code :

```
#!/bin/bash

Body='{
    "event_id": "12",
    "metric_name": "API",
    "value" : "1",
    "dimensions": {  
    },
    "timestamp_ms": 1615552313
}';

seq 1 2 | xargs -n1 -P10 curl --location --request POST '10.33.137.98:8080' --header 'Content-Type: text/plain' --data-raw "$Body"
```

But how to calculate time like P95 , P90 etc ?

Answer (score 2):

I also couldn't get `xargs -P` working when I needed to do something similar, and I ended up using `&`.

From `man bash`:

> If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell.  The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0.  These are referred to as asynchronous commands.

So something like this, maybe?

```
#!/bin/bash

Body='{
    "event_id": "12",
    "metric_name": "API",
    "value" : "1",
    "dimensions": {  
    },
    "timestamp_ms": 1615552313
}';

function run() {
    for i in $(seq 1 10); do
        echo "running task $i"
        curl --location --request POST '10.33.137.98:8080' --header 'Content-Type: text/plain' --data-raw "$Body" &
    done 

    wait
}

time run
```

Explanations:

- `time` is used to measure total execution time, see `man time`
- `wait` ensures that all the background jobs finish before continuing, otherwise the `time` would just measure how long to launch all the requests, not how it took to get a response
- [`parallel` might also work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9262360/14269772) instead of `&`

To calculate statistics, you could output the time of each request, using a second `time` call in the `for` loop, and then process it using your favourite analysis tools.

Answer (score 1):

Make a bash function. Call it from GNU Parallel. Use `--joblog` to see timing.

```
doit() {
    curl --location --request POST 'MY_IP' \
    --header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
    --data-raw ' [{
        "event_id": "123",
    }]    
    '
}
export -f doit
seq 10000 | parallel -j 10 --joblog my.log doit
```

Now look at my.log.

GNU Parallel has an overhead of 1-10 ms per job, so if your `curl`s are really short, you could do more than one:

```
seq 10000 | parallel -j 10 --joblog my.log 'doit;doit;doit;doit;doit;doit;doit;doit;doit;doit'
```